Need help setting up SATA RAID ARRAYS
I built a system with the following in it: 8TB NVMe Chips (4), 4TB SATA SSD DRIVES (2), 16TB SATA HDD (2).I am trying to figure out what SATA ARRAY SETTINGS TO UTILIZE and
the suggestion are: NVMe's RAID5 ; The SSDs RAID 0; and the HDD RAID 10 so far what say you?Please Help

Before setting up a SSD RAID0, I would check if your SATA controller is able to handle such high speeds. Most mainboard SATA controllers are not able to handle higher speeds than 6Gbit/s in total. So I recommend to buy a dedicated RAID controller card SAS/SATA for the SSD and using the mainboard SATA controller for the HDD. The NVMe drives should form their own RAID. PS please also read about RAID modes, RAID 10 needs 4 drives

Thank You very much seriously. I set the NVMe's up on RAID 5 if memory serves, I'd been up for 16 hrs by that time. and set up the SATA SSDs and SATA HDDs together as a RAID 10. Right now the Boot Drive is one of the SSDs 2TB SATAs. I'm imaging  that by setting the up as an RAID 10 They will all be the Boot Drive in so far as windows is concerned

Question sir: would that RAID CONTROLLER DRIVE  be available in BEST BUY or Newegg ?
